# Trying to generate crud module getting error

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm using MeanJs and trying to follow a tutorial. I am getting this error when I try to put in this line into the cmd terminal:

```
yo meanjs:crud-module customers
```

Once I have put this in I get this in response:

```
You don't seem to have a generator with the name meanjs:crud-module installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 2 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have it installed, it would seem you have to install it:

`npm install -g generator-meanjs`

From these docs:

http://meanjs.org/generator.html

Comment: What output do you get when you run the command verbosely: `npm --loglevel verbose install -g generator-meanjs`

Comment: Make sure you use the `-g` flag too, for `global`... its possible you installed it in a local directory instead?

Comment: I ran the command you told me too and after about a minute of it doing something at the very end it said this: npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok

Comment: Okay, what happens when you run `yo --help`... do you see the generator is available?

Comment: Hmm... this might be an issue with the generator itself? Check out this issue queue from GitHub: https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues/79

Comment: generator is available when i do yo --help. And I tried to do the command they said to do:  yo meanjs:vertical-moduule meets and still got the same exact error.

Comment: Are you running the subgenerator from the root of the install?

Comment: oh the available generators I have are mean and meanjs

Comment: I am running it from the mean app I created , I'm not sure if that is correct or not

Comment: Were you ever prompted with this command at the beginning of generation: `What mean.js version would you like to generate?`... it seems like that sub-generator might not be available in every version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99532/discussion-between-pizzasynthesis-and-newbiecoder).

Answer (score 0):

The current generator is not stable and does not have the crud-module sub generator anyways.

Please try this:

sudo npm remove -g generator-meanjs

This should remove the generator that you have installed.

Then install the generator version on which this course is built: sudo npm install -g generator-meanjs@0.1.12

After that, do a "yo meanjs" on any folder and see if you are able to generate the site. The crud-module generator should also work.

If you actually want to use the latest (unstable) generator, you would have to follow what they have now. For e.g., the equivalent of crud-module in the latest version is "yo meanjs:vertical-module